# How to change the filename in a FileTransfer object via any API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, fuel-sdk, wsdl

I would like to change the filename in a FileTransfer object via the SOAP API (or any other API)?

I know I can Perform the FileTransfer but not edit it because FileTransferDefinition is not part of the WSDL.

Is there a way to Perform it passing a different filename in the call maybe?

Comment: Hi @Seb, As you see, you can't directly manipulate the File Transfer's properties, but might Triggered Automations work for you use case?

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/

With these, the filename itself is used as a variable, "FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER" or "BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER" that can be used in File Transfers and Import Activities within your Automation.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMcLeod, thanks for your idea, it is a valid one.
But in my case, Automations are not Triggered but Scheduled and run at a certain time. I know an option would be to add a Wait step in the Automation until the time I want it to run but that's pushing a bit as I don't know when the file arrives on the FTP and they might change the file before actual run time.

Comment: Actually in my case, I'm starting the Automation in SSJS in a Landing Page and I need to update the FileTransfer filename before starting it.